# Safari Web Inspector - any way to return to selected element on reload

Tags: safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

Is it possible to have the Safari web Inspector retain the position that the DOM tree is expanded to?

At present, you expand the DOM tree to an element and then as soon as the page is refreshed the entire DOM structure is collapsed again necessitating drilling right the way back to the original element.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189949/how-do-i-keep-the-elements-dom-tree-open-in-the-webkit-inspector) on the subject a couple of years back but the code has now changed so it doesn't apply.

I have also opened [a bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=121665) at the WebKit bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bug ended up getting fixed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=121665